# CSS is ignoring @media only screen criteria

Tags: html, css, dreamweaver

Why does nothing I do on my CSS style sheet work?

I have the following code which displays a placeholder `div` when on a desktop screen and to disappear when it's displayed on a mobile/tablet screen.

```css
@media only screen and (min-width: 940px) {
  .image_placeholder {
    display: block;
  }
}

.image_placeholder {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="image_placeholder">
  This is an image placeholder
</div>
```

Why can't I get this to work: Set the `.image_placeholder` with css to`display:none;` when the screen width is below 920px and set it to  `display:block;` when it is at 920px or above.

Why does the `.image_placeholder` disappear regardless as to whether the screen is above or below the 920px threshold?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the missing `.` in front of the second `image_placeholder` isn't there in the actual code:

CSS rules, when selectors are of equal specificity, are applied **in order**.

So, if the media query **applies**:

```
.image_placeholder { display:block; }
.image_placeholder { display:none; }
```

So it gets `none`.

If the media query **doesn't** apply, then you just have:

```
.image_placeholder { display:none; }
```

So it gets `none`.

**Order matters**.

If you want the media query rules to override the non-media query rules then put the media query **last**.

Answer (score 1):

You should write the media query after the main CSS.

```css
.image_placeholder {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 940px) {
  .image_placeholder {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="image_placeholder">
  This is an image placeholder
</div>
```

**Edit:**

An example code with image would be like this -

```css
.image_placeholder {
  display: none;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 940px) {
  .image_placeholder {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="image_placeholder">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/500x500.jpg">
</div>

<p>This is sample text to test that the placeholder image div leaves no white space in mobile resolution.</p>
```

Comment: OK, it's partly there, but now I just get a blank space where the image should be.....

Comment: I have added a code snippet with an image. The image would disappear in mobile view as you mentioned in your question. Does your code have additional html that is leaving the blank space?

Comment: No it hasn't but for some reason it's now fixed. In all honesty I did not realise there had to be an order with media query and non media query's. So thanks .

Answer (score 0):

You should add full stop . in-front of class name like .image_placeholder.

Comment: I appreciate that, that was my mistake which I corrected on here, my actual code has the full stop.

Comment: You didn't have. Sorry bro that's true!